# Highlight one bar of a stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar chart and, inspired by [Figure 3.8](http://serialmentor.com/dataviz/color-basics.html#fig:popgrowth-US-highlight) on [this](http://serialmentor.com/dataviz/color-basics.html#color-as-a-tool-to-highlight) page, I would like to highlight one bar of the bar chart. For example, I'd like all three colours for middle bar to be a notch darker and all the colours in the 1st and 3rd bars to be a little lighter. I'm assuming that the `darken` argument to `scale_fill_OkabeIto` could come in handy in some way.

```
library(ggplot)    
library(colorblindr)
ID <- rep(1:3, each = 3)
group <- rep(letters[1:3], times = 3)    
prop <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3)

toy_df <- data.frame(ID = ID, group = group, prop = prop)

ggplot(toy_df, aes(x = ID, y = prop, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_OkabeIto()
```

Below is the graph so far:
[image]

I have seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820250/highlight-a-single-bar-in-ggplot) showing how to do this for regular bar charts but can't figure out how to do this for a stacked bar chart.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do something like this is to change the alpha based on whether the ID is the one you want highlighted. You could make a boolean variable in your dataframe, something like `isHilite = ID == 2`, or you can just do it inline when you plot.

I dropped your color scale just because I don't have that package installed, and it wasn't necessary to show you this example.

Another option if you want to get into more complex color functions is the [`munsell` package](https://github.com/cwickham/munsell) that works with a whole different color system. I haven't used it enough to put together a good answer with it, but it has functions for darkening, lightening, and desaturating color.

```r
library(ggplot2)    
ID <- rep(1:3, each = 3)
group <- rep(letters[1:3], times = 3)    
prop <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3)

toy_df <- data.frame(ID = ID, group = group, prop = prop)

ggplot(toy_df, aes(x = ID, y = prop, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(aes(alpha = ID == 2), stat = "identity") +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1, "FALSE" = 0.6), guide = F)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do it, simply mapping alpha to whether the ID is a given value.

```
ggplot(toy_df, aes(x = ID, y = prop, fill = group, alpha=toy_df$ID != 2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0.7)) +
  guides(alpha=F)
```

[image]

Of course, you can still use your colour-blind friendly colour set with this

Comment: Having `toy_df$` inside an `aes` call could cause errors

Comment: If so, add an extra line: `toy_df$isdark <- toy_df$ID != 2`, then map alpha to `toy_df$isdark`

Comment: That works, but you want to always do `aes` calls like `alpha = isdark` or `alpha = ID != 2`, without including the name of the dataframe

Comment: it can cause scoping problems, for one. Here are a couple posts where that comes up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860112/how-to-properly-use-variable-in-ggplot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156155/misplaced-points-in-ggplot `ggplot` is expecting the columns you give it to be within the dataframe it's operating on, so it's better to just match the expected input